# Close idle socket on server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Hi
i would like to close a connection on server that client is disconnected from server app but connection remains open. Is there a way ? any C# snippet code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the client disconnects cleanly, then you'll get a 0-byte read from `EndReceive`. You can then close the socket.

If the connection is broken, then you'll need a way to detect it. You need to *send data* over a socket to detect when the other side has disconnected. This will result in an exception being thrown on your next socket operation (e.g., `EndReceive`), and you can then close the socket.

I have a more detailed explanation in my blog entry [Detection of Half-Open (Dropped) Connections](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sockets should be closed when:

1. An exception is thrown for any of the socket methods.
2. Receive/EndReceive returns 0 bytes
3. Send/EndSend returns 0 bytes.

Simply use `socket.Close()` on those occasions.

Comment: receive seems to be good solution but when it returns 0 byte if we put that socket in receive mode ? on receive timeout or ??

Comment: You have to implement ALL of the mentioned items. `Receive` should return 0 as soon as the client disconnects (or an exception might be thrown). Note that this applies for TCP sockets.